# Simulating a circuit with initial conditions given in a loop with PySpice

Tags: python, initialization, simulation, circuit, pyspice

I try to simulate the following simple RC circuit, to use finite element method to verify my solution to a slightly altered transmission line problem.

[image]

While it is not directly related to the question, `R(i)`, `R(0i)` or `C(i)` are not necessarily equal to each other.

All nodes in the bottom rail have the same potential with each other at the start of the simulation. Similarly, all nodes in the top rail have the same potential at the start.

I can generate this circuit with PySpice in a loop, i.e.,

```py
for i in range(1, number_of_branches - 1):
    circuit.R('R'+str(i), 'n'+str(i), 'n'+str(i+1), 1000@u_Ω)
for i in range(1, number_of_branches - 1):
    circuit.R('R_'+str(i), 'n_'+str(i), 'n_'+str(i+1), 1000@u_Ω)   
for i in range(1, number_of_branches-1):
    circuit.C('C'+str(i), 'n'+str(i), 'n_'+str(i), 100@u_μF)
```

However, I cannot generate the initial conditions in a loop. If I type all nodes individually, i.e.,

```py
simulator.initial_condition(n1=ic,n2=ic,n3=ic,n4=ic,n_2=0,n_3=0,n_4=0)
```

the simulation results give me what I want. But this is just impossible for large number of branches. The main issue is that `n1, n2, n_1, n_2...` are variables recognised only by the circuit methods. These nodes are created with the string names passed when circuit elements are created if they don't already exist. I looked deep into the code. I tried to check all objects created by the `circuit` method to get a list of nodes which I can use to pass initial conditions but it seems above my python skills.

How can I provide initial conditions in a loop? This could be by passing a dictionary as well. I have the minimum working example below.

```py
import PySpice.Logging.Logging as Logging
logger = Logging.setup_logging()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PySpice.Probe.Plot import plot
from PySpice.Spice.Netlist import Circuit
from PySpice.Unit import *

circuit = Circuit('Test')
steptime=.1@u_us
finaltime = 1000@u_ms
number_of_branches = 6
ic=100@u_mV


for i in range(1, number_of_branches - 1):
    circuit.R('R'+str(i), 'n'+str(i), 'n'+str(i+1), 1000@u_Ω)
for i in range(1, number_of_branches - 1):
    circuit.R('R_'+str(i), 'n_'+str(i), 'n_'+str(i+1), 1000@u_Ω)   
for i in range(1, number_of_branches-1):
    circuit.C('C'+str(i), 'n'+str(i), 'n_'+str(i), 100@u_μF)
circuit.C('C'+str(number_of_branches-1), 'n'+str(number_of_branches-1), circuit.gnd, 100@u_μF)
ra = circuit.R('Ra', 'n1', 'n_1', 10@u_Ω)


simulator = circuit.simulator(temperature=25, nominal_temperature=25)
simulator.initial_condition(n1=ic,n2=ic,n3=ic,n4=ic,n_2=0,n_3=0,n_4=0)
analysis = simulator.transient(step_time=steptime, end_time=finaltime)


figure = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 6))
axe = plt.subplot(111)
plot(analysis['n3']-analysis['n_3'], axis=axe)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I posted a solution in case someone needs something that works, even if it is suboptimal. My approach is by no means the best solution. I will accept if someone posts a solution that shows how to pass initial conditions in a loop or with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize if I haven't formatted this correctly, this is my first answer to a SO post.
Below is what I believe you are looking for:

```
kwargDict = {}
for n in netlist.node_names:
    kwargDict[n] = IC
simulator.initial_conditions(**kwargDict)
```

Pyspice's source code shows that it will accept any kwarg dictionary with the string name of the node, and a value, so you can modify kwargDict however you like to change initial conditions as you please. when you are done pass it with the double asterisk (**) to simulator.initial_conditions in place of the arg list. So from your example:
(n1=ic,n2=ic,n3=ic,n4=ic,n_2=0,n_3=0,n_4=0) becomes:

{'n1':ic,'n2':ic,'n3':ic,'n4':ic,'n_2':0,'n_3':0,'n_4':0}, the dict with string names as keys and the IC values as the values

hope this helps!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This actually helps a lot! I will make sure to accept this answer as soon as I had the time to check it!

Meanwhile, you could use triple quotations (this one: "`" but three times) around the inline code snips, like ```{'n1': ic, 'n2': ic}```. Your response is perfectly useful but bots would be unhappy if you do not do that :)

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution, I decided to use switches.

I used switches to connect all nodes in the upper rail to an `ncc` node that is kept at `Vcc` and all nodes in the bottom rail to an `ndd` node that is kept at `Vdd` node. The switches are initially closed and which forces all nodes at the desired values. They open at some time after which I assume the simulation starts.

Codewise, I remove the following line.

```py
simulator.initial_condition(n1=ic,n2=ic,n3=ic,n4=ic,n_2=0,n_3=0,n_4=0)
```

And add the following function.

```py
def switch_generator(circuit, number_of_branches, switchingtime):
    circuit.PulseVoltageSource('SV', 'SVN', circuit.gnd,initial_value=1, pulsed_value=-1,
                        pulse_width=finaltime, period=finaltime, delay_time=switchingtime)
    circuit.R('SR1', 'SVN', circuit.gnd, 1@u_kΩ)
    circuit.V('Vcc', 'ncc', circuit.gnd,   100@u_mV)
    circuit.V('Vdd', 'ndd', circuit.gnd,   0@u_mV)
    for i in range(1, number_of_branches - 1):
        circuit.VoltageControlledSwitch('S'+str(i), 'n'+str(i), 'ncc','SVN', circuit.gnd, model='switch')
    for i in range(2, number_of_branches - 1):
        circuit.VoltageControlledSwitch('S_'+str(i), 'n_'+str(i), 'ndd','SVN', circuit.gnd, model='switch')
    return circuit
```

The values I am looking for are almost identical between the two simulation. The difference is at the 7th significant figure after the decimal point.

There is some associated computational burden with this approach. The switching process seems to bring a one time extra burden but dissipates in ratio for long simulations.

Comment: This is just one step better than passing all initial conditions by hand. Thus, I will accept a solution that shows how to pass initial conditions in a loop or with a dictionary.